# leaks when using NSData, NSURL,NSMutableURLRequest,NSURLConnection and sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: nsurlconnection

I am getting the leak at this line in below code"   NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection ..........."

NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:curl];
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL 
                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                timeoutInterval:10];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 BOOL enabled = [self getAutoGenerateObject:returnData];
 return enabled;

please help me out of this problem.
Thank You,
Madan  Mohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to release the returnData. That's why in Apple's examples in 'URL Loading Programming Guide / Using NSURLConnection', the returnData is assigned to an iVar and release in dealloc or connectionDidFinishLoading in the case of Asynchronous communication.

Depending what operation you are performing in you method getAutoGeneratedObject, but in theory it can take ownership there.

You could also mark returnData as autoreleased, but that is not always recommended especially if the response data is large.

```
NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:curl]; 
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL 
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                                      timeoutInterval:10]; 
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; 

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 

BOOL enabled = [self getAutoGenerateObject:returnData]; 

[returnData release];

return enabled;
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? This is in direct contravention of Cocoa's memory management rules, and the static analyzer should call you out on it. If this hack really is required, then it should be reported to Apple as a bug.